# targetSdkVersion changes to 26 for sdk's

Tags: android, sdk, targetsdkversion

If I am currently developing an SDK module for an Android application, do I still need to set my targetSdkVersion to 26 from now on in order for the client application to approve (from Nov 2018)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.  From the [developers post](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) the app is the only thing required to be targeting API 26.

What could happen is the following scenario: imagine that your module is targeting an old API level and uses a deprecated method. If your app targets a more recent API where that method was removed, your app may not compile.

Hope this can help you. Cheers!